# Seleccionar registros más recientes de dos tablas

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql, mysqldb

Buen Día a Todos!!
Alguien podría apoyar con la siguiente consulta!!
Tengo dos tablas como se muestra en la imagen; donde requiero obtener los siguientes datos: ID, ARCHIVO, MD5 de la tabla 1, MD5 de la Tabla 2, ESTATUS, FECHA_1, FECHA_2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla 1; Obtener los siguientes datos:
El ID = 10, ARCHIVO = A y B, MD5, ESTATUS = 1, FECHA = Los registros más recientes, en éste caso serán únicamente los dos registros con el estatus = 1 (color verde)
Tabla 2:
Requiero el MD5 de la fecha más reciente de esos dos registros que traigo de la tabla 1.

He intentado algo como esto pero me muestra 4 registros pero deberían ser solo dos registros:

```
SELECT   T1.ID, 
         T1.ARCHIVO, 
         T1.MD5 AS MD5_T1, 
         T2.MD5 AS MD5_T2, 
         T1.ESTATUS,   
         MAX(T1.FECHA) AS FECHA_T1, 
         MAX(T2.FECHA) AS FECHA_T2   
FROM   TABLA_1 AS T1 
JOIN TABLA_2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
AND T1.ARCHIVO = T2.ARCHIVO      
WHERE   T1.ID = 10 AND T1.FECHA = CURRENT_DATE AND T1.ESTATUS = 1         
GROUP   BY T1.ID, T1.ARCHIVO, T1.MD5, T2.MD5, T1.ESTATUS, T1_FECHA, T2_FECHA
```

Alguna idea??.. Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y si... esta haciendo lo correcto... porque decis que deberian ser 2 y no 4? yo claramente veo que son 4 registros los que cumplen esa condicion de join...

Comment: Hola, Gracias por el dato, quizá no formulé adecuadamente mi pregunta. Gracias!!.

Comment: Entonces usa el boton [edit] y arregla tu pregunta asi alguien puede responderla...